# Xpath 2.0 - converting numerical value into words

Tags: xpath-2.0

Currently struggling to convert a numerical value being taken from an XML into words e.g 1 to be replace by "one".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.0 or 3.1 one can use the standard **[`format-integer()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-integer)** function.

**Example**:

```
format-integer(125, 'w')
```

**produces**:

```
one hundred and twenty five
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am working with Xpath 2.0, are you suggesting there isn't a viable solution on this older version?

Comment: One could try and implement the algorithm for generating the correct English pronunciation of any integer, but I am not sure doing this in pure XPath 2.0 would be a good and valuable experience. As for working with XPath 2.0, one can always start using newer versions of Saxon, even in the browser, and these support XPath 3.1

Comment: @ThatkidRiq Just get Saxon/C. It implements XPath 3.1 and can be used from Python, PHP, C (of course), Linux in general. https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml